# Why my "UPDATE" SQLITE3 in javascript is not working?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, express

so I have this code, but sometimes this.changes = 0 and sometimes this.changes = 1. i have no idea why
in my code, there is db.run that update sqlite3 database. sometimes this.changes is 1 but sometimes this.changes is 0. can someone help me to this.changes is always 1?

````
app.post("/like/:noteId", (req, res) => {
  //TODO first the shuf we will be false
  shuf = false;
  const noteId = parseInt(req.params.noteId.trim());
  
  //TODO next we will be search the position of noteId
  let itemIndex = -1;
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i].noteId == noteId) {
      itemIndex = i;
      break;
    }
  }

  if (itemIndex !== -1) {
    const item = data.splice(itemIndex, 1)[0];
    data.unshift(item);
    if (!item.hasLiked) {
      //TODO like usualy,the script will run the database first

      db.run("UPDATE data SET Like = Like + 1 WHERE noteId = ?", [noteId], function(err) {
        item.like++
        if (err) {
          return console.log(err.message);
        }
        console.log(`Row(s) updated: ${this.changes}`);
        item.hasLiked = true;
        res.cookie(`liked_${noteId}`, "true");
        res.redirect("/");
      });
    }
  }
});```
````

Comment: Where do you define or set `this.changes`? And when do you use it? Because in your posted code, it is only used inside the console.log.

Comment: because i want to try if there is any changes on the database. but is sometimes 0 and sometimes 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `WHERE` clause in your `UPDATE` statement matches no rows in your table, it changes no rows, and therefore returns 0 in `.changes`.